# Check items by size and position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a little problem. I have an array of objects that are mixed in different sizes. The condition is to order them in increasing form, from small to big. I did the arrangement as shown in the code below, but now I did not know how to check if they were ordered or not.

```
foreach (GameObject palm in thisPalms)
        palm.GetOrAddComponent<MouseEventSystem>().MouseEvent += thePalmHasClicked;

    private void thePalmHasClicked(GameObject target, MouseEventType type)
{
    if (type == MouseEventType.CLICK && canClick)
    {
        int targetIndex = System.Array.IndexOf(thisPalms, target);

        if (targetIndex != lastTargetIndex && lastTargetIndex != -1)
        {
            canClick = false;
            thisPalms[lastTargetIndex].transform.DOMove(thisPalms[targetIndex].transform.position, 1f).SetDelay(0.5f);
            thisPalms[targetIndex].transform.DOMove(thisPalms[lastTargetIndex].transform.position, 1f).SetDelay(0.5f).OnComplete(() =>
            {
                canClick = true;
                lastTargetIndex = -1;
                moveIndex -= 38;
                levelIndex++;

                //Here I have to check if they are ordered or not
                //if is ordered => DoNext();
                //else => DoBad();

            });
        }
        lastTargetIndex = targetIndex;
    }
}
```

Objects are palm trees of different sizes. If anyone has any idea what to use and how, thank you.

Comment: Is this a school assignment? In your example it is unclear what determines the size of a palm. If a palm (GameObject) has some kind of size property you could iterate over the palms and check if they are in increasing order.

Comment: Your 'gameobject' has a [Transform property](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-transform.html) which has [localScale](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localScale.html) and [position](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html) You might want to start there.